# how to add javafx dependencies in maven with java 10

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, java-10

I switched to ubuntu 18.04.
Which has java 10 as default jvm

Now my apps that use javafx cannot compile anymore.

```
 cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ObservableMap
```

I tried to add parameters to the maven-compiler-plugin to load the javafx.graphics module.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                    <arg>javafx.graphics</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

result :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] module not found: javafx.graphics
```

of course, java --list-modules | grep fx returns nothing.

I've spent more than 10 hours trying to figure this out.

TL:DR What am I supposed to do to compile my JavaFX modules with Java 10?

minimum project :

/pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>java10fx</name>

    <artifactId>java10fx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <groupId>my.test</groupId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>10</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

/src/main/java/MyApp.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp  extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {}

}
```

error :

```
java10fx/src/main/java/MyApp.java:[1,26] package javafx.application does not exist
```

Comment: adding minimum example

Comment: Few things to clear, are you building a modularised code? what's your maven configuration(what java version)? Also, have added the tag for Ubuntu, since on MacOS I am able to build a similar application quite comfortably.

Comment: just the two files I specified and mvn copile. my java version is 
openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17

Answer (score 6):

OpenJDK never contained JavaFX and from Java 11 on, neither will Oracle JDK, so JavaFX will have to become a regular dependency. OpenJFX, the project behind JavaFX, has recently [released an early access build of a standalone JavaFX SDK](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-May/021819.html) that works with Java 10 and 11, but it is not yet available on Maven Central (that is planned for the future).

For now, you have to [download the SDK](http://jdk.java.net/openjfx/) manually and find a way to add it to your Maven build, for example by deploying it to your Nexus or including it in a folder in your repo. Once it is available on Maven Central you will be able to use it just like any other dependency.

Comment: this does not concern java 11?

Comment: thank you , so at the moment I can't build the app but when maven repo will contain it I will..

Comment: @guigolum Yes, you can build the app, you just can't rely on Maven Central alone. If you don't run a Nexus, [answers to this question should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/2525313).

Comment: This answer is a little out of date - the dep is now in Maven Central: https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/HelloFX/Maven

Comment: Related question on "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894627/how-to-fix-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-ru/58498686#58498686

Answer (score 2):

ok so actually the issue is kinda complex.

The OPENJDK version installed with ubuntu is a mix between java 10 and java 11 : the package installed is actually "openjdk-11" but the VM installed refers to itself as openjdk-10 . Just as openjdk-11 it does not provide the javafx modules.

The solution was to install the oracle jdk 10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
```

And then the minimum program I gave works.

Also I purged everything eg sudo apt remove --purge "openjdk-11*"